# Change the size of the GUI window tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've tried to change the window size for this GUI but i'm struggling. I tried to use root.geometry("1080x800+200+200") but that doesnt seem to work as well. Can someone explain why? i'm currently just practicing using tkinter. thanks

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3
TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you mean by `root.geometry` doesnt work well?

Comment: i tried to use root.geometry but it didn't make the window bigger, it  just created a new window in the size i wanted.

Comment: `root.geometry` changes the tkinter window size. do you mean the python console isnt changing?

Comment: There's no window named `root` in that code you posted. Your root window is named `app`. So you should call `app.geometry("1080x800+200+200")`. BTW, you should fix your indentation.

Comment: ah yes @PM2Ring i didnt pick up on that because i commented as soon as i saw that `root,geometry` wasnt working well i didnt look at the code :D

Comment: by windows size i'm talking about the GUI it self

Comment: There's no call to `geometry` in your code, and no widget named `root`.

Comment: never mind i fixed it.
i'm so stupid, i was using root.geometry from another program :) 
 `if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry("1080x800+200+200")
    app.mainloop()`

Answer (score 5):

You do not have a root declared in your program so you will not be able to call `root.geometry`. If you change your code to something like this then you will be able to call `root.geometry` and change the size of your GUI window, also by using `root` you can pass it in as a parameter to your other page classes and set different sizes for them all if you wish.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1080x800+200+200") 
    app = SampleApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i'm so stupid, i was using that from another program :) It works now but instead of doing what you did i just done
 `if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = SampleApp()
     app.geometry("1080x800+200+200")
     app.mainloop()`

Comment: In this example you do _not_ want to create root. `SampleApp` subclasses `Tk`, so you just need to call `geometry` on `app`.

Answer (score 1):

In first class SampleApp you can just use `self.geometry('500x555') #for example`.